# Can python + pandas be used to correlate list of strings?

Tags: python

I have a lot of string data in lists, i.e.

```
['red','tall','cat']
['dog','car','tall','green']
```

etc. - about 10000 of these

The lists can contain 1 to ~70 items. The items are drawn from a list of about 120 possibilities.

Can pandas do correlation on this so I can see what items `red` correlates to most strongly, or most negatively, i.e. I want to know if `red` is in a list. How likely is it that cat will also be in that list?

Comment: You will need word embeddings and then yes they can be used to do that.

Comment: when you say "correlates most strongly", do you mean which words are more frequently present in each row containing `red` for example?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like a frequent itemset problem.

There are several python packages out there, including [apyori](https://pypi.org/project/apyori/) or [mlxtend](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/apriori/#api).

An example from the mlxtend user guide:

```py
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori

dataset = [['Milk', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Dill', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Milk', 'Apple', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs'],
           ['Milk', 'Unicorn', 'Corn', 'Kidney Beans', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Corn', 'Onion', 'Onion', 'Kidney Beans', 'Ice cream', 'Eggs']]

te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)
df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)

frequent_itemsets = apriori(df, min_support=0.6, use_colnames=True)
frequent_itemsets['length'] = frequent_itemsets['itemsets'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

You can then filter by length or by support to find the items that most frequently appear together.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Sorry it was meant to be a comment but I didn't have enough reputation. So instead I've changed answer to be more like a proper answer. @Nihal Sangeeth Thanks for the tip!